# How to Convert a X509CertImpl to a X509CRLEntry

Tags: java, x509

I'm trying to Convert a X509CertImpl to a X509CRLEntry so I can generate my X509CRLImpl but I can't find a way of doing this, isn't is supposed to be easy? The CRL should be made of revoked X509 Certificates so it has to be an easy way!

I'm using sun.security.x509 and java.security.cert packages

Thank you for the Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRLs don't contain certificates consequently you can't get a certificate from the CRL.